# Common idiom in Java to Scala, traverse/Iterate Java list into Scala list

Tags: java, scala, idioms

I am processing a XML document and iterating through nodes.  I want to iterate through the nodes and build a new List of some type.  How would I do this with Scala:

Here is my XML traverse code:

```
  def findClassRef(xmlNode: Elem) = {

    xmlNode\"classDef" foreach { (entry) =>
        val name    = entry \ "@name"
        val classid = entry \ "@classId"
        println(name + "//" + classid)
    }
  }
```

Where the line of println is, I want to append elements to a list.

Answer (score 4):

Map should work. If you do not need exactly a List instance you can remove the toList.

```
xmlNode \"classDef" map { (entry) =>
  val name    = entry \ "@name"
  val classid = entry \ "@classId"
  name + "//" + classid
} toList
```

Comment: That would work.

Is there is no "append to list" way of doing this?

Comment: @Berlin Why do you want to explicity append to a list? ‘map‘ appends to a new collection internally.